# Android Bluetooth connection issue when mobile battery low

Tags: android, bluetooth

Its Morly like a logical issue, I found a strange behavior of my Samsung galaxy tab, I have created a application which will has a Bluetooth connectivity and communication, So problem is when my mobile battery is down (on critical stage or 15% remaining) mobile doesn't connect with the Bluetooth device don't know why? Does any one found similar problem??

Comment: I believe most Samsung Devices have a power saving mode somewhere within the settings that when the battery gets below a certain point it disables certain components. Maybe this is the problem

Comment: I checked that too but it not going to drop connection...Also it will not trouble to do new connection..